# How to print code in two columns per page?

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, printing

In an old computer in my previous job (talking about 2012), I used Notepad++ and I could print my code neatly in two columns per page.

Since then I haven't been able to replicate that. I don't know if it is a problem of not knowing how to use Notepad++ or something about the drivers of the printer.

How can you print code so that it is printed in two columns per page?

NOTE:
I remember in my old computer I got something like this

[image]

I cannot get this anymore.How can I get this menu?

Comment: Strictly speaking you were not printing 2 cols per page, you were printing 2 pages at half size side-by-side.  This is handled by the print driver. You should add your OS and printer  model.

Comment: so I should update the printer's driver?

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, so I don't know, but that could be a solution.  If it doesnt work, I imagine you can print 2 pages per sheet to a PDF, then print the PDF.  (Google came up with https://winaero.com/blog/print-pdf-multiple-pages-windows-10-keep-page-order/ )